# How to prevent a function from continuing after a return statement in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function that checks if a value is valid or not.  This function will then be put inside another function to check if the rest of the function should continue.  My idea basically looks like this:

```
def test(value):
    if value == 5:
        return "Don't Continue"

def go(number):
    test(number)
    print('Here')
    return 'Yes'
    print('Now here')

go(5) # Returns "Don't Continue", 'Here'
```

Why doesn't the function quit executing when the `test` function returns a value, and, is there a way to create this type of test without a multiline if, else situation?

Comment: You don't test the returned value from `test`; you don't always return a value from `test`.  You might invent a better name for the function, such as `is_expected_value()` perhaps.  You'd then have it return a boolean value: True or False (rather than a string or, at best, None).

Comment: Right, I wanted the function to continue (i.e. not return) if that test fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why doesn't the function quit executing when the test function returns
>   a value

Because a return statement only applies to the function it's in, not to the function that called the function.

You want something like this

```
def test(value):
    if value == 5:
        return False
    return True
    # these 3 lines can be shortened to: return value == 5

def go(number):
    if test(number): # test(value) returned True
        print('Test succeeded')
        return
    print('Test failed')

go(5) # will print 'Test failed'
```

> is there a way to create this type of test without a multiline if,
>   else situation?

If you mean to check for multiple values, you can do it like this

```
def test(value):
    # will return False if value is either 3 5 or 7
    if value in [3, 5, 7]:
        return False
    return True
```

The logic is a little off, though. It's better to return True if a test passed and False if it didn't.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way you can go if your program might take many routes, and you want to avoid many `if` statements:

```
def test(value):
    return value == 5


def passed():
    return 'Passed'


def failed():
    return 'Failed'


def router(value):
    routes = {
        True: passed,
        False: failed,
    }
    result = test(value)
    return routes[result]


def main(value):
    route = router(value)
    return route()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(main(5))
    print(main(4))
```

Comment: if I am not wrong, should it be just 'return route' instead of 'return route()' under 'def main(value)'.

Comment: @PEJK in this case no, because the `router` returns a function, and i want to call it, so i use `()`

Answer (score 0):

`return` means return from the current function. So calling another method that returns does not return from the method that calls it.

You could raise an exception in the `test` method. That would stop execution.

Or you could change `go` to have:

```
if test(number):
    return
```

so it would discontinue the method depending on the result of calling `test`.